# Affinity propagation vs basic k-means algorithm

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a dataset consists of (700 data points x 400 dimensions) which belong to 10 classes. I did cluster this data to see how data points will fit into clusters similar to their class. I performed two clustering experiments, one using basic k-means (euclidean) and another using Affinity Propagation. I noticed that the results using k-means are better and faster!! than the Affinity Propagation.

I could not understand the reason behind this. Can any of you help in giving explanation why I got such results (I thought Affinity Propagation is better than k-means)?

Comment: "Better" - by what measure? If you measure SSQ, k-means will win by design.

Comment: Thank you @Anony-Mousse for your comment. I am using the following measure (cluster purity, accuracy, sensitivity, specificity,F-Measure,Precision) because I know the class labels of data points so I can calculate these measures.

Answer (score 2):

It could be a matter of granularity - the APC result could be close to a subclustering or superclustering of the class labels. There is a parameter that affects APC granularity (check yourself).

Another consideration is how you prepare the network that you give to APC (or any other network clustering algorithm). Ideally it should not be too dense. As a rough guideline, make sure that the distribution of `{ number of neighbours per node | all nodes }` does not stray far outside `[0.5 * sqrt(N) - 2.0 * sqrt(N)]`. Especially try to avoid hubs, that is, nodes that have many more neighbours than that upper bound.

As a sanity check, are the values that you give to APC *similarities*? They should similarities be of course, not distances. You have a choice how the similarity is computed. The standard way to restrain the number of neighbours is to use a cut-off. Experiment with the combination of these. Finally you may also want to try MCL, an algorithm that precedes APC and uses conceptually similar principles but is a bit cleaner in its formulation (alternation of simple matrix operations). It is probably faster.